# following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data : DbContextOptions'1options

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, xunit.net, asp.net-core-1.1

```cs
   public class StudentService
    {   


}
```

I have a student class where I am accessing MsDbContext to do entity framework related work.In the above code, options are coming from abstractDbBasedService.

AbstractDbBasedService :

```cs
public class AbstractDbBasedService

}
```

Now, I have a test class where I am accessing all the above services.

StudentTestClass :

```cs
    public class StudentServicesTests : AbstractDbBasedService
    {

}        
       [Fact]
        public void Assert_CreatedStudent_WhenStudentParemeterInvalid()
        {

        }

}
```

when I am trying to the run the tests, It is giving me the error - The following constructor parameter did not have matching fixture data:DbContextOptions'1 options. Please help me on this.

Comment: Why aren't you using the search function? I answered the exact same question just a day ago here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349140/xunit-di-through-overridden-startup-file-net-core/41350245#41350245. In short: You can't inject services into Test classes, only fixtures and only then when you implement `IClassFixture<T>` or `ICollectionFixture<T>` in your test class

Comment: I am using asp.net core1.1 and Autofixtures(from nuget package manager) is not supported for Asp.net core1.1

Comment: AutoFixture is ASP.NET Core agnostic, it's only dependency is the Unit Test framework, you just need to target `net452` in your test library instead of `netcoreapp1.1`